# System Reliability affecting work duties

Tags: communication

On several instances, at work reliability issues with applications have caused decreases productivity. The unavailability of a system have affected other members of the team.

To give an example, I was trying to validate change documentation in our JIRA system today to make sure that code defects were documented and resolved prior to production deployment from sandbox. As a result of application downtime, I will be squeezed to complete the work by the end of the week. HelpDesk supported is contracted.

One of my goals in discussion is to have application support / HelpDesk support become more efficient to minimize downtime in the future.

**How do I discuss this with my manager that lack of system reliability is affecting work?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you just go to your manager and tell him the same thing that you wrote here? This seems well organized, factual and with a clear and specific ask.

Comment: And the added bonus of not having anything insulting/offensive in it.  It is acceptable to go directly to the manager with what you have.

Answer (score 4):

IN this situation, I would document the issues and downtimes (start time, end time, communication with helpdesk etc, response times) so that you have documented facts to present to your manager.

As a contracted helpdesk, there should be SLAs in place and hopefully these are being met. If not, this is also something that your manager should be aware of.

This is not "telling tales" but simply putting facts in place to back up perception. I've worked in support functions before and hearing users say "the system is ALWAYS down" is of no use to anyone unless it truly is down 100% of the time. As the helpdesk or application vendor, I'd want this information to be able to spot patterns and assist in some resolution approach.

You need this information to have the discussion with your manager. You are essentially doing the work that they will tell you to do so that they can escalate your concerns. You can also discuss with them contingency for deadlines based on the likelihood that the application will be down